# Will saving uploaded images as base64 text prevent attackers from uploading harmful code to server?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

So I've been researching a bit on how to be sure that the file which user is uploading to your website is actually an image, and not a file of some other format.

While there are many ways to prevent honest users from accidentally uploading a file which is not an image, there doesn't seem to be a single PHP function which 100% prevents attackers from uploading harmful code to your server.

Since most attacks revolve around uploading PHP code, or any other code to your server, and then executing it trough browser in one way or another, I was wondering if simply saving the uploaded file as base64 would do the trick?

Any harmful script would be turned into base64 gibberish, and would not be executable.

Comment: Just store the files somewhere outside the web root so that they can't be executed. If a file can't be executed it can't do any damage.

Comment: Prepend a single byte and most files are corrupted...

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I don't have access to anything outside of web root.

Comment: @HonkderHase Wouldn't that corrupt the images as well?

Comment: Of course :) If you modify a binary file, you're most likely destryoing it if you'd use it as a surrogate. Example: If you ZIP an executable and try to run the ZIP as if was the executable, it won't run - but the _original_ file is still present... if you know how to reconstruct it.

Comment: @defranz I think it unlikely that you don't have access outside the web root. If that's actually the case, change the access permissions to a directory within the web root so that the web server won't serve files from there. How you do that depends on the web server you're using. If you can't do either of those things, change your hosting arrangements.